# How to fix error: Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set the a state with an array of objects but I'm getting the above error and I do not know how to resolve it.

My code:

```
const [itemsInCart, setItemsInCart] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=16")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const initialItemCount = data.map((item) => {
            return {
              name: item.title,
              qty: 0,
            };
          });
          setItemsInCart(initialItemCount);
        });
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

I tried `console.log(Array.isArray(initialItemCount))` to check if it is an array and it returned true. So why is it saying to use an array? Thank you

Comment: How do you render that data? The error indicates that you are trying to render an object in your return statement

Comment: You are most probably trying to directly render `itemsInCart` as it is in the state, not really mapping it to `jsx` elements. On a side note, choose to either use `fetch(...).then` syntax or `async...await` syntax. Mixing them defeats the purpose of `async...await`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a breakpoint to see the final value of `itemsInCart`, to check if this array contains the list of React child component.

From your code, I guess the array only contains the object of {name and qty}, which can not be rendered directly.

You may try parsing these objects to a component to render UI.

Hope this help.